# How to synchronise asynchronous methods in RxJava? Async Waterfall in RxJava

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, rx-java, async.js

**With RxJava, how to sequentially execute asynchronous methods on a list of data?**

Using the Node.js *[Async](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#every)* module it is possible to call a function over an array of objects sequentially in the following fashion:

```js
var dataArray = ['file1','file2','file3']; // array of arguments
var processor = function(filePath, callback) { // function to call on dataArray's arguments
    fs.access(filePath, function(err) { // perform an async operation
        // process next item in dataArray only after the following line is called
        callback(null, !err)
    }
};
async.every(dataArray, processor, function(err, result) {
    // process results
});
```

What's nice about this is that code executed within the `processor` function can be asynchronous and the `callback` can be run only once the async task is finished. This means that each object in dataArray will be processed one after another, not in parallel.

Now, in RxJava I can call a processing function over dataArray by calling:

```
String[] dataArray = new String[] {"file1", "file2", "file3"};
Observable.fromArray(dataArray).subscribe(new Consumer<String>() { // in RxJava 1 it's Action1
    @Override
    public void accept(@NonNull String filePath) throws Exception {
        //perform operation on filePath
    }
});
```

However, if I perform an asynchronous operation on `filePath`, how can I ensure the sequential execution on items of dataArray? What I'd be looking for is something along the lines of:

```
String[] dataArray = new String[] {"file1", "file2", "file3"};
Observable.fromArray(dataArray).subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
     // process next item in dataArray only after the callback is called
    @Override
    public void accept(@NonNull String filePath, CallNext callback) throws Exception {
         // SomeDatabase will call callback once
         // the asynchronous someAsyncOperation finishes
         SomeDatabase.someAsyncOperation(filePath, callback);
    }
});
```

And furthermore, how do I call some code once all items of `dataArray` have been processed? Sort of a 'completion listener'?

*Note: I realise I'm probably getting the RX concept wrong. I'm asking since I can't find any guideline on how to implement the Node.js' Async pattern I mentioned above using RxJava. Also, I'm working with Android hence no lambda functions.*

Comment: Have you looked at concatMap()? Please try something like this

Observable.from(fileNameList).concatMap((fileName) -> processFile(fileName).susbscribeOn(Schedulers.io())).subscribe()

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of days of trial and error, the solution I used for this question is as follows. Any suggestions on improvement are most welcome!

```
private Observable<File> makeObservable(final String filePath){
    return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<File>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<File> e) throws Exception {
            // someAsyncOperation will call the Callback.onResult after
            // having finished the asynchronous operation.
            // Callback<File> is an abstract code I put together for this example
            SomeDatabase.someAsyncOperation(filePath, new Callback<File>(){
                @Override
                public void onResult(Error error, File file){
                    if (error != null){
                        e.onError(error);
                    } else {
                        e.onNext(file);
                        e.onComplete();
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    });
}

private void processFilePaths(ArrayList<String> dataArray){
    ArrayList<Observable<File>> observables = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String filePath : dataArray){
        observables.add(makeObservable(filePath));
    }
    Observable.concat(observables)
            .toList()
            .subscribe(new Consumer<List<File>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull List<File> files) throws Exception {
                    // process results.
                    // Files are now sequentially processed using the asynchronous code.
                }
            });
}
```

In short what's happening:

1. Turn `dataArray` into an array of Observable's
2. Each Observable performs the asynchronous operation at the time of subscription and feeds the data to `onNext` after the async operation finishes
3. Use `Observable.concat()` on the array of Observable's to ensure sequential execution
4. Use `.toList()` to combine the results of Observable's into one List

While this code does what I require, I'm not entirely satisfied with this solution for a few reasons:

1. I'm not sure if executing the asynchronous code within the `Observable.create()...subscribe(){` is the right way to use Observable's.
2. I read that using Observable.create should be used with caution ([ref docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables))
3. I'm not sure the behaviour I'm trying to achieve requires creating a new Observable for each item in the `dataArray`. It seems more natural to me to have one observable that is capable of releasing data sequentially - but again, that may be just my old style of thinking.
4. I've read that using `concatMap` should do the trick, but I could never figure out how to apply it to this example, and found `concat` doing just the trick. Anyone caring to explain the difference between the two?

I also tried using `.zip` function on the array of Observable's before, and while I managed to get the List of results at the end, the async operations were executed in parallel not sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

One very simple and easy way to perform asynchronous operations (calculations etc.) is to use the [**RxJava Async Utils**](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaAsyncUtil) library (not written by me, just used in our code).

- Easiest way to run a method in a background thread is to use `Async.start(this::methodToCall, Schedulers.io())` which returns an `Observable<T>` that produces the return value of the passed method after the method call completes.
- There are many other alternative methods that allow you to e.g. report intermediate results via an `Observer<T>`

If you want to use `Observable.from()` and `concatMap()` (or similar ways) remember to first move the processing to a background scheduler with `.observerOn(Schedulers.io())` or any other scheduler you want.

Comment: `concatMap()` lead me to the right path thanks! As a side note: *RxJavaAsyncUtils* I've seen before yet couldn't find any documentation on it hence I decide to avoid using it for now. Also, this::methodToCall wouldn't work, it's Java 7 I'm needing to use. Thanks for suggesting either way!

Comment: You can use the old way of using an anonymous class implementation of Func0<T>, you don't have to use the lambda syntax. Or even better - you can use [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) which converts Java 8 lambda syntax to Java 7 classes during compile time. I use that myself for Android apps. Async Utils also has a Javadoc which explains the interface, it's just not linked in the project page, which they should fix.

Answer (score 0):

To call a function over an array of objects sequentially, you need not any async facilities. Just make a for-loop over the array.
If you need that loop to execute asynchronously, then please describe what asynchrony you need: either to start the loop after array is asynchronously filled, or you want to react asynchronously to the result of the computation, or both. In either case, class [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) may help.

Comment: Well correct, calling a function over an array sequentially could use a simple for-loop, but the code executed within the loop is asynchronous and after the loop I need to process the updated objects from the array. I've been needing this functionality in various places, but one I'm working on right now is a function that given a list of Post objects fetches appropriate images from the server with Glide without causing timeouts that parallel fetching causes with a higher number of simultaneous requests. I don't mind losing speed for sake of robustness here.